# knockoutjs using module pattern not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, module-pattern

I am trying to create simple knockout example using module pattern

```
var login = {}; //login namespace

//Constructor
login.UserData = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.UserName = ko.observable("");
    self.Password = ko.observable("");
};
//View-Model
login.UserVM = function () {
    this.userdata = new login.UserData(),
    this.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:9090/',
    this.authenticate = function () {
        var data = JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(this.userdata));
        var service = apiUrl + '/api/Cryptography/Encrypt';
        DBconnection.fetchdata('POST', service, JSON.stringify(data.Password), response, function () { console.log('Cannot fetch data') }, null, true);
        function response(res) {
            console.log(res)
        }
    }
    return {
        authenticate: this.authenticate
    }
}();

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(login.UserVM); /* Apply the Knockout Bindings */
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginForm" method="POST">
    <div id="form-root">
        <div>
            <label class="form-label">User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" data-bind="value:login.UserData.UserName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="form-label">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" data-bind="value:login.UserData.Password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" data-bind="click: authenticate" />                
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the problem is am not able to get userdata in the viewmodel on click of submit it is returning undefined and the login object holds the changed value of textbox but on click it is returning black values.
please let me know

Also can you let me know how to implement definative module pattern in the same code.

Comment: Should be `ko.applyBindings(new login.UserVM())`

Comment: @adiga i have been refering to this https://codepen.io/dustinpage/pen/Kwmgj?editors=0010 and UserVM is already executing

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was an IIFE

Answer (score 1):

The object you are returning from `login.UserVM` has only `authenticate` property and doesn't have `userdata` or `apiUrl` properties. So, instead using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create an object, set `login.UserVM` to a constructor function similar to `login.UserData`. And then use [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) to create the viewModel object. Now the viewModel will have `userdata` and `apiUrl` properties (remove the `return` from the function)

Also, you need to change the HTML bindings to: `data-bind="value:userdata.UserName"`. This looks for the `userdata` property inside the bound `viewModel`

```js
var login = {}; //login namespace

//Constructor
login.UserData = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.UserName = ko.observable("");
    self.Password = ko.observable("");
};
//View-Model
login.UserVM = function () {
    this.userdata = new login.UserData(),
    this.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:9090/',
    this.authenticate = function () {
        var data = JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(this.userdata));
        console.log(data)
        //var service = this.apiUrl + '/api/Cryptography/Encrypt';
        //DBconnection.fetchdata('POST', service, JSON.stringify(data.Password), response, function () { console.log('Cannot fetch data') }, null, true);
        function response(res) {
            console.log(res)
        }
    }
}; // remove the () from here

ko.applyBindings(new login.UserVM()); /* Apply the Knockout Bindings */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form id="loginform" name="loginForm" method="POST">
    <div id="form-root">
        <div>
            <label class="form-label">User Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" data-bind="value:userdata.UserName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="form-label">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" data-bind="value:userdata.Password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" data-bind="click: authenticate" />        
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How to use definitive module pattern in this?

Comment: @abhishek Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean by "*how will i be able to return value*". (Also, I'm not aware of  definitive module pattern to help with that)